# How to define a controller for a directive in a separate js file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
.directive('directiveName', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templateurl/abc.html',
        scope: {
            name: '@',
            flag: '='
        },
        controllerUrl: 'controllerurl/xyz.html'
    }
}]);
```

While defining directives in angularjs, is there a way to specify a url for the controller of the directive? (Similar to defining `templateUrl`) Something like a `controllerUrl` parameter maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the controller in any file and use `controller: 'name-of-controller'`. Make sure the file where the controller is located gets imported in your index.html

Comment: keep in mind your controller should belong to the same module as your directive, or your directive's module should have a dependency to the one that owns the controller. https://jsfiddle.net/h29Lfk9t/